# ASP.NET dropdown combobox with images

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, combobox

From my asp.net web forms, I need to use a dropdown combobox with images instead of text.

I have found this plugin ddSlick http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick that works fine, but I need to set like "SET selected Dropdown Option" from code-behind doesn't works.

This is code that I use:

```
string jquery = "$('#ddimages').ddslick('select', {index: 2 });";
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "blah", jquery, true);
```

nothing happens...

How can I do to set dropdown index from code-behind?

Comment: A better way would be to pass the parameter as query string to the page and manipulate your JQuery

Comment: I don't like develop client side mixing server side, so I have used http://www.obout.com/combobox perfect for my purpose